# How to avoid auto correction of numbers in rubocop

Tags: ruby, rubocop

How to avoid auto correction of numbers in rubocop. I don't think the following is correct.

```
-        (Time.now.to_i * 10000).to_s
+        (Time.now.to_i * 10_000).to_s
```

Comment: Why don't you think it's correct?  https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/lib/rubocop/cop/style/numeric_literals.rb

Comment: It might be irritating that a tool like Rubocop modifies your code, but think about WHY you are running it: It's so you can learn how your code should look for common usage in the community. `10_000` is a readability/maintenance thing. You *should* use underscores in the thousands columns to help others (and your future you) read the value. In corporate coding groups you'll encounter a lot of variations on desired programming style, and they should boil down to readability because, in the long run, the more easy code is to read, the faster it can be debugged when the world is in flames.

Comment: I do understand why I am running it, I just don't like the style "."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you disagree with that rule, you should disable it in your Rubocop configuration file.  I think you have to add the following to `.rubocop.yml`:

```
NumericLiterals:
  Enabled: false
```